# How to determine whether an eigenstate of total spin is symmetric or antisymmetric?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, identical-particles

Here we have two identical paticles with spin $I$, integer or half-integer,
and there are $(2I+1)^2$ states.

Each one of them can be uniquely determined by total spin and its orientation, we can use $|J,m\rangle$ to represent this state. And because of its uniqueness, it is either symmetric or antisymmetric.

How to determine whether $|J,m\rangle$ is symmetric or antisymmetric based on $I$, $J$ and $m$?

Comment: Are you referring to the spatial part of the wave-function, or the spin part, or the whole thing? Because if they are fermions, it has to be antisymmetric under particle exchange.

Comment: @lionelbrits only spin part.

Comment: One can easily show, via a highest-weight construction, that when two particles of spin $I$ are coupled, the resulting states with $J = 2I$ are always symmetric and the states with $J = 2I-1$ are always antisymmetric.  I suspect that this logic continues on down the chain, i.e., the parity of any state under exchange is $(-1)^{J-2I}$;  and the value of $m$ is irrelevant.  However, the proof technique I thought up for the $J = 2I$ & $J = 2I - 1$ cases fails at $J = 2I-2$.  If I come up with a general proof, I'll be sure to post it.

Answer (score 7):

Let's denote the spins of the individual particles by $j_1 = j_2 = I$, the quantum numbers for the $z$-components of their angular momentum by $m_1$ and $m_2$, the spin of their combined state by $J$, and the $z$-component of the angular momentum of the combined state by $M$.  We have two bases for the states of these particles:  the "individual particle" basis, denoted by
$$
|I \, m_1 \, I \, m_2 \rangle
$$
and the "combined particle" basis, denoted by 
$$
|J \, M \rangle.
$$
(Note that $j_1$ and $j_2$ are also still "good" quantum numbers for this latter state;  but including them in both notations is redundant and can confuse things, so I'll omit them.)  Finally, let's denote by $\hat{E}$ the exchange operator between particles 1 & 2, i.e., we define $\hat{E}$ such that
$$
\hat{E} |I \, m_1 \, I \, m_2 \rangle = |I \, m_2 \, I \, m_1 \rangle.
$$

We can perform a basis transformation to express any state $|J \, M \rangle$ in terms of the basis $|I \, m_1 \, I \, m_2 \rangle$:
$$
|J \, M \rangle = \sum_{j_1, m_1, j_2, m_2} |I \, m_1 \, I \, m_2 \rangle \langle I  \,m_1  \,I \, m_2 | J \, M \rangle 
$$
The coefficients $\langle I  \,m_1  \,I \, m_2 | J \, M \rangle$ are known as the [Clebsch-Gordan coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients).  We want to know what happens when we apply the exchange operator $\hat{E}$ to this state:
$$
\hat{E} |J \, M \rangle = \sum_{j_1, m_1, j_2, m_2} |I \, m_2 \, I \, m_1 \rangle \langle I  \,m_1  \,I \, m_2 | J \, M \rangle = \sum_{j_1, m_1, j_2, m_2} |I \, m_1 \, I \, m_2 \rangle \langle I  \,m_2  \,I \, m_1 | J \, M \rangle
$$
(The second step is just a relabelling of dummy indices $m_1$ and $m_2$ in the sum.)  We can see that $|J \, M \rangle$ will be an eigenstate of $\hat{E}$ if and only if all of the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients $\langle I  \,m_1  \,I \, m_2 |J \, M \rangle$ are multiplied by the same factor when we exchange $m_1 \leftrightarrow m_2$.  Thankfully, the Clebsch-Gordon coefficients satisfy the identity
$$
\langle j_1  \,m_1  \, j_2 \, m_2 | J \, M \rangle = (-1)^{j_1 + j_2 - J} \langle j_2  \,m_2  \, j_1 \, m_1 | J \, M \rangle
$$
and so we have
\begin{multline}
\hat{E} |J \, M \rangle = \sum_{j_1, m_1, j_2, m_2} |I \, m_1 \, I \, m_2 \rangle \left[ (-1)^{2I - J} \langle I  \,m_1  \,I \, m_2 | J \, M \rangle  \right] \\ = (-1)^{2I - J} \sum_{j_1, m_1, j_2, m_2} |I \, m_1 \, I \, m_2 \rangle  \langle I  \,m_1  \,I \, m_2 | J \, M \rangle = (-1)^{2I - J} |J \, M \rangle.
\end{multline}
Thus, **the combined states are symmetric when $2I$ and $J$ are both even or both odd, and antisymmetric when one quantity is even and the other is odd.**

Comment: Side note: the Clebsch-Gordan identity I used is the one given in both MathWorld and Wikipedia.  However, when I tried to derive it from the stated properties of [Wigner 3-j symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol) (as suggested in the Wiki article), I obtained $\langle j_1  \,m_1  \, j_2 \, m_2 | J \, M \rangle = (-1)^{j_1 + j_2 + J} \langle j_2  \,m_2  \, j_1 \, m_1 | J \, M \rangle$ (note the sign difference in the exponent.)  It doesn't matter for this problem because $J$ is always an integer, but it'd be great if someone could check my work and let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: The source for this stuff is the book of Varshalovich.  The phase change given there is $(-1)^{j_1+j_2-J}$.  The $3j$'s have some weird phase w/ to the CGs which make their use tortuous compared to CGs.

Answer (score 3):

The final states $\left|j,m\right\rangle$ arising from the coupling of two angular momenta $j_{\alpha}$
and $j_{\beta}$ are related to the initial uncoupled states $\left|j_{\alpha},m^{\alpha}\right\rangle,  \left|j_{\beta},m^{\beta}\right\rangle$    through the so called *Glebsch-Gordan coefficients* $  C_{jm^{\alpha}m^{\beta}}^{j_{\alpha}j_{\beta}}$
\begin{equation}
\left|j,m\right\rangle =\sum_{m^{\alpha},m^{\beta}}^{m^{\alpha}\!+m^{\beta}=m}C_{jm^{\alpha}m^{\beta}}^{j_{\alpha}j_{\beta}}\left|j_{\alpha},m^{\alpha}\right\rangle  \left|j_{\beta},m^{\beta}\right\rangle
\tag{01} 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}  
  & j=\vert j_{\alpha}-j_{\beta}\vert,\vert j_{\alpha}-j_{\beta}\vert+1 , \cdots , j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}\\
  & m=-j,-j+1, \cdots , j-1,j\\
  & m= m^{\alpha}+m^{\beta}\\
  & m^{\alpha} = -j_{\alpha},-j_{\alpha}+1, \cdots, j_{\alpha}-1,j_{\alpha}\\
  & m^{\beta}  = -j_{\beta},-j_{\beta}+1, \cdots, j_{\beta}-1,j_{\beta}\\
  & \left|j_{\alpha},m^{\alpha}\right\rangle  \left|j_{\beta},m^{\beta}\right\rangle=\left|j_{\alpha},m^{\alpha}\right\rangle  \boldsymbol{\otimes}\left|j_{\beta},m^{\beta}\right\rangle
 \end{split}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
These coefficients are given by equation (03)
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
 & C_{jm^{\alpha}m^{\beta}}^{j_{\alpha}j_{\beta}}=\\
 & \frac{\sqrt{\left(j+j_{\alpha}-j_{\beta}\right)!\left(j-j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}\right)!\left(j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}-j\right)!\left(j+m^{\alpha}+m^{\beta}\right)!\left(j-m^{\alpha}-m^{\beta}\right)!}}{\sqrt{\left(j+j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}+1\right)!\left(j_{\alpha}-m^{\alpha}\right)!\left(j_{\alpha}+m^{\alpha}\right)!\left(j_{\beta}-m^{\beta}\right)!\left(j_{\beta}+m^{\beta}\right)!}}\\
 &\times \sum_{\varkappa}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\varkappa+j_{\beta}+m^{\beta}}\sqrt{\left( 2j+1\right) }\left(j+j_{\beta}+m^{\alpha}-\varkappa \right)!\left(j_{\alpha}-m^{\alpha}+\varkappa\right)!}{\left(j-j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}-\varkappa \right)!\left(j+m^{\alpha}+m^{\beta}-\varkappa \right)!\varkappa!\left(\varkappa + j_{\alpha}-j_{\beta}-m^{\alpha}-m^{\beta}\right)!}
 \end{split}
\tag{03}   
\end{equation}
The variable $\,\varkappa\,$ in series takes all nonnegative integer values for which all factorials have sense.

Interchanging $j_{\alpha}$ and $j_{\beta}$ and simultaneously $m^{\alpha}$ and $m^{\beta}$ yields
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
 & C_{jm^{\beta}m^{\alpha}}^{j_{\beta}j_{\alpha}}=\\ 
 & \frac{\sqrt{\left(j+j_{\alpha}-j_{\beta}\right)!\left(j-j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}\right)!\left(j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}-j\right)!\left(j+m^{\alpha}+m^{\beta}\right)!\left(j-m^{\alpha}-m^{\beta}\right)!}}{\sqrt{\left(j+j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}+1\right)!\left(j_{\alpha}-m^{\alpha}\right)!\left(j_{\alpha}+m^{\alpha}\right)!\left(j_{\beta}-m^{\beta}\right)!\left(j_{\beta}+m^{\beta}\right)!}}\\
  &\times \sum_{\varkappa}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\varkappa+j_{\alpha}+m^{\alpha}}\sqrt{\left( 2j+1\right) }\left(j+j_{\alpha}+m^{\beta}-\varkappa \right)!\left(j_{\beta}-m^{\beta}+\varkappa\right)!}{\left(j+j_{\alpha}-j_{\beta}-\varkappa \right)!\left(j+m^{\alpha}+m^{\beta}-\varkappa \right)!\varkappa!\left(\varkappa - j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}-m^{\alpha}-m^{\beta}\right)!} 
 \end{split}
\tag{04}
\end{equation}

As pointed out in Wigner<sup>(1)</sup>  $\; C_{jm^{\alpha}m^{\beta}}^{j_{\alpha}j_{\beta}}$ will remain unchanged  if $j_{\alpha}$ and $j_{\beta}$ and simultaneously $m^{\alpha}$ and $m^{\beta}$ are interchanged and on this result the factor $\left(-1\right)^{j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}-j}$ is applied
\begin{equation} 
C_{jm^{\alpha}m^{\beta}}^{j_{\alpha}j_{\beta}} =\left(-1\right)^{j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}-j} C_{jm^{\beta}m^{\alpha}}^{j_{\beta}j_{\alpha}}
\tag{05}
\end{equation}
Note that under a second interchange the overall factor would be $\left(-1\right)^{2\left(j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}-j\right)}=+1$ as expected, since $\left(j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}-j\right)$ is always a (non-negative) integer.

So for $j_{\alpha}=I=j_{\beta}$ the two coefficients differ by $(-1)^\left(2I-j\right)$ and in agreement with  Michael Seifert's answer :

> *the combined states are symmetric when $2I$ and $j$ are both even or both odd, and antisymme- tric when one quantity is even and the other is odd.*

---

Examples :

> 1. $\qquad j_{\alpha}=\frac{1}{2}=j_{\beta}$

<sup>\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{2}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{2}=\boldsymbol{1}\boldsymbol{\oplus}\boldsymbol{3}
\nonumber
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}  
\left|0,\hphantom{\!\!-\!}0\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|\frac12,\!\!-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}}\\
\left|1,\!\!-\!1\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|\frac12,\!\!-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}}\\
\left|1,\hphantom{\!\!-\!}0\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|\frac12,\!\!-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}}\\
\left|1,\!\!+\!1\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|\frac12,\!\!-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}} 
\end{bmatrix}
       =
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-\rho\hphantom{+}&+\rho\hphantom{+}&0\vphantom{\left|\frac{1} {2},\!\!-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}}\\
+1\hphantom{+}&0&0&0\vphantom{\left|\frac{1} {2},\!\!-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}}\\
0&+\rho\hphantom{+}&+\rho\hphantom{+}&0\vphantom{\left|\frac{1} {2},\!\!-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}}\\
0&0&0&+1\hphantom{+}\vphantom{\left|\frac{1} {2},\!\!-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\left|\frac{1}{2},\!\!-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac{1} {2},\!\!-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}\\
\left|\frac{1}{2},\!\!-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac{1}{2},\!\!+\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}\\
\left|\frac{1}{2},\!\!+\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac{1}{2},\!\!-\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}\\
\left|\frac{1}{2},\!\!+\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|\frac{1}{2},\!\!+\frac12\right\rangle_{\beta}
\end{bmatrix}
 \, , \quad \rho = \sqrt{\tfrac12}
\tag{Ex-01}   
\end{equation}</sup>

<sup>$\boldsymbol{1} : \left|0,\,0\,\right\rangle \Longrightarrow \text{antisymmetric}$</sup>

<sup>$\boldsymbol{3} : \left|1,\!\!-\!1\right\rangle,\left|1,0\right\rangle,\left|1,\!\!-\!1\right\rangle\Longrightarrow \text{symmetric}$</sup>

---

> 2. $\qquad j_{\alpha}=1=j_{\beta}$

<sup>\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{3}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{3}=\boldsymbol{1}\boldsymbol{\oplus}\boldsymbol{3}\boldsymbol{\oplus}\boldsymbol{5}
\nonumber
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
  \begin{bmatrix}  
  \left|0,\hphantom{\!\!-\!}0\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} \\
  \left|1,\!\!-\!1\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}}  \\
  \left|1,\hphantom{\!\!-\!}0\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}}  \\
  \left|1,\!\!+\!1\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} \\
  \left|2,\!\!-\!2\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}}  \\
  \left|2,\!\!-\!1\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}}  \\
  \left|2,\hphantom{\!\!-\!}0\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}}  \\
  \left|2,\!\!+\!1\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}}  \\
  \left|2,\!\!+\!2\right\rangle\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} 
  \end{bmatrix}
  \!=\!
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0&0&+\sigma\hphantom{+}&0&-\sigma\hphantom{+}&0&+\sigma\hphantom{+}&0&0\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} \\ 
  0&-\rho\hphantom{+}&0&+\rho\hphantom{+}&0&0&0&0&0\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} \\ 
  0&0&-\rho\hphantom{+}&0&0&0&+\rho\hphantom{+}&0&0\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} \\ 
  0&0&0&0&0&-\rho\hphantom{+}&0&+\rho\hphantom{+}&0\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} \\ 
  +1\hphantom{+}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} \\ 
  0&+\rho\hphantom{+}&0&+\rho\hphantom{+}&0&0&0&0&0\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} \\ 
  0&0&+\tau\hphantom{+}&0&+\upsilon\hphantom{+}&0&+\tau\hphantom{+}&0&0\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} \\ 
  0&0&0&0&0&+\rho\hphantom{+}&0&+\rho\hphantom{+}&0\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} \\
  0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&+1\hphantom{+}\vphantom{\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta}} 
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta} \\
  \left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|1,\hphantom{\!\!-\!}0\right\rangle_{\beta} \\
  \left|1,\!\!-\!1  \right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|1,\!\!+\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta} \\
  \left|1,\hphantom{\!\!-\!}0\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta} \\
  \left|1,\hphantom{\!\!-\!}0\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|1,\hphantom{\!\!-\!}0\right\rangle_{\beta} \\
  \left|1,\hphantom{\!\!-\!}0 \right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|1,\!\!+\!1\right\rangle_{\beta} \\
  \left|1,\!\!+\!1 \right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|1,\!\!-\!1 \right\rangle_{\beta} \\
  \left|1,\!\!+\!1 \right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|1,\hphantom{\!\!-\!}0\right\rangle_{\beta} \\
  \left|1,\!\!+\!1\right\rangle_{\alpha}\left|1,\!\!+\!1\right\rangle_{\beta}
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \,, \:
  \begin{matrix}
     \rho = \sqrt{\frac12} \\
     \sigma = \sqrt{\frac13}\\
     \tau = \sqrt{\frac16}\\
     \upsilon = \sqrt{\frac23}
  \end{matrix}
\tag{Ex-02}   
\end{equation}</sup>

<sup>$\boldsymbol{1} : \left|0,\,0\,\right\rangle \Longrightarrow \text{symmetric}$</sup>

<sup>$\boldsymbol{3} : \left|1,\!\!-\!1\right\rangle,\left|1,0\right\rangle,\left|1,\!\!-\!1\right\rangle\Longrightarrow \text{antisymmetric}$</sup>

<sup>$\boldsymbol{5} : \left|2,\!\!-\!2\right\rangle,\left|2,\!\!-\!1\right\rangle,\left|2,0\right\rangle,\left|2,\!\!+\!1\right\rangle,\left|2,\!\!+\!2\right\rangle \Longrightarrow \text{symmetric}$</sup>

---

<sup>(1)
Wigner Eugene P. *"Group Theory and Its Application to Quantum Mechanics of Atomic Spectra" (1959)* : as refered in the footnote of page 192 the two coefficients differ, using our symbols, by the factor $\left(-1\right)^{j_{\alpha}+j_{\beta}-j}$.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For spin-1/2 particles, the entire wavefunction has to be antisymmetric under particle exchange. Also, the spatial component has parity $(-1)^\ell$, so if $\ell$ is even, the spin component must be odd under exchange.